# How this iterative function is O(n/2) when I calculate it and gives me O(n^3)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have this function

```
void A()
{
    for(int i=n/2;i<=n;i++)
        printf("XXX");
}
```

and I tried to compute it's complexity with the following logic (but I know it's wrong and the correct value is O(n/2) according to [tutorial 24:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEnwM-iDb2g&t=1870s)):

> i value  initially starts with i= n/2; then i=(n/2)+1; then i=(n/2)+2; >>>> i=(n/2)+n.

This will lead to total number of execution n/2*(1 +2 +3 +4 + ....+ n)
which will be n^2 definition, therefore it will have a value of O(n^3).

Comment: `n` is neither declared nor initialized; what is `n`?

Comment: The runtime of your code is O(n/2) since the for loop iterates over a range of n/2 (from n/2 to n).

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. `i` goes from `n / 2` to `n`, that's `n / 2` iterations (give or take one), so the complexity is `O(n / 2)`, a.k.a. `O(n)`.

Comment: @Timo I know it takes O(n/2) but I failed with analyzing  the loop

Comment: The sum of an arithmetic progression (1+2+...+n) is (n-1)*n/2. ~n^2. Multiplying to n/2 gets n^3

Comment: It seems like you have a confusion between time and the values that variables take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i value initially starts with i= n/2; then i=(n/2)+1; then i=(n/2)+2;
>   i=(n/2)+n.

Final value is `i=(n/2)+n/2 = n`, not `(n/2)+n` as you assumed; so it is extremely easy to deduce the total number of operations: `end - start + 1`, which is `n - n/2 + 1 = n/2 + 1`, and that is `O(n)`.

Comment: That being said, usually constant factors are omitted if the runtime bound is polylogarithmic, i.e. `O(n/2)=O(n)`.

Comment: @Codor Agreed, that's why I mentioned `O(n)` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an easy example since we know exactly how many iterations the for loop will count according to `n`: `i` will sequentially take the values `n/2`, `n/2+1` ... `n`.

The loop will iterate exactly `n-n/2+1` = `n/2+1 (+parity)`, hence the algorithm complexity is O(n/2) = O(n).